# Difficulty of exercises in several books

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-number-theory

Since I am teaching myself, I have no idea of the difficulties of exercises in many books. I want to know whether I am not understanding the content of these books if I cannot easily solve the exercises. I am trying to figure out the (general, without *'s) difficulty of exercises in these following books.

1. Lang, Algebra
2. Neukirch, Algebraic Number theory
3. Manfredo, Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces
4. Hatcher, Algebraic Topology.
5. Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry

Should I be able to solve more than half of the exercises given in these books if I truly understood? Or what books' exercises can be hard for me to solve more than half even though I understood its content?

I am asking this because I am trying to stay in each chapter until I finish solving almost every exercises in it if its exercises are not that hard for me to solve.

Comment: You should stick with the exercises even if they're hard for you to solve. Sometimes important theorems are left to exercises, but even more importantly, if you solve all the exercises, you'll leave each chapter with a **far** better understanding of the material than if you hadn't.

Comment: I believe so, too. However I believe that there might be very hard problems such as 'the' problem in Lang, Algebra Second edition, or the problems in one book are generally hard, such that it may be better for me to read farther, become more familiar with those subjects, and come again to solve the remaining exercises.

Comment: If you don't manage an exercise (after having seriously attacked it), go ahead, read the next chapter, and go back later. That way you might gain some intuition.

Comment: No, you shouldn't be able to solve half of the exercises in these books because they are quite difficult and non-routine. For Hartshorne, a solving rate of 10% to 20% would be quite a success! There are books more suitable for self-study than those in your list. Many questions on this site where exactly about them: try using the excellent "search" function on this very page (upper right-hand corner).

Comment: I don't think that you might solve all exercises. I can only speak about Hatcher's book: I had an Algebraic Topology course, where we solved at most 5 exercises per week, where the most exercises came from Hatcher's book. I think you should solve most of the "computation"-exercises (for example: calculate the fundamental group...), but the "proof"-exercise are sometimes extremely difficult. Maybe you should choose a few exercises for each topic. But this is only a subjective point of view. Otherwise your question depends on how good you want to be in Algebraic Topology. ;-)